# "col-md-*" not working with infragistics grid

Tags: css, angular, infragistics, ignite-ui-angular

I have a basic html table and infragistics(igx) grid displaying data:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"> 
           <table> </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
           <igx-grid #grid1 [data]="localData" [autoGenerate]="true"></igx-grid>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css file is:

```
@import "~igniteui-angular/lib/core/styles/themes/index";
@include igx-theme($default-palette);


  table { 
    width: 100%; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
  }
  th { 
    background: #333; 
    color: white; 
    font-weight: bold; 
  }
  td, th { 
    padding: 6px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    text-align: left; 
  }
```

This is what is in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^8.6.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "igniteui-angular": "^8.2.9",
    "jszip": "^3.1.5",
    "minireset.css": "~0.0.4",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.19",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.19",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "igniteui-cli": "~4.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
```

My idea was to get both the table and grid on a same row but this isn't happening.
Will igx related css override it?
In the dev-tool styles, It uses "core.scss" and "minireset.css" mostly.
How do I move forward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of those packages or the Ignite UI for Angular theme should interfere with Bootstrap's grid classes. `igx-theme` rules target the components specifically and font properties under the `.igx-typography` class. `minireset.css` rules are global, but deal with browser inconsistencies with basic elements.

Mind you, unless those are `@import`-ed in your `styles.scss`, added as styles in the `angular.json` config or in the `index.html` page, that CSS is not included in your running app. And it looks like you might be missing the Bootstrap CSS.

You should have something like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

in your `index.html` from I see in `@ng-bootstrap` examples.

That seems to work just fine, see https://angular-8gmxfj.stackblitz.io

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8gmxfj

PS: You also have the `bootstrap` package installed, so I guess you can also import from there:

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap";
```

Not sure why you'd have both packages, since `bootstrap` one brings peer dependencies on `jquery` and `popper.js`, which is exactly why `ng-bootstrap` replaces it for Angular usage.

Comment: I installed md-bootstrap and it worked fine, but somehow the infragistic grid doesn't go well with it. I used `row` and `col` classes of md-bootstrap but it made the grid crunched and I can't resize it. Any thoughts?

Comment: The `row` and `col-X` classes still come from Bootstrap itself, right? As far as I can tell md-bootstrap only adds extra styles. I tried adding the md-bootstrap css from their CDN after Bootstrap in the sample above and the layout is still fine.
Perhaps you can make a similar sample (or modify the one above) to show what's stuck with the sizing.